# onSavedInstanceState doesn't save my Instance

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hope you're all doing fine in these tough times.

I have 2 activities, A and B.

A has a button that enables an intent to go from A to B. B itself has a Dialog window whom's `cancel` button enables an Intent to go from B to A.

I'd like to save some data from A (2 EditTexts' content) so when I come back to A I don't have to retype those EditTexts.

So after looking up the documentation and a bit of StackOverflow, I decided to go with the `onSavedInstance` method but I'm wondering whether the intent transition destroys the Activity and hence the savedInstance as well...

Here's my simplified code - Activity A :

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_match);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            EditText firstPlayer = findViewById(R.id.firstPlayerName);
            EditText secondPlayer = findViewById(R.id.secondPlayerName);

            String firstPlayerName = savedInstanceState.getString("firstPlayerName");
            String secondPlayerName = savedInstanceState.getString("secondPlayerName");

            firstPlayer.setText(firstPlayerName);
            secondPlayer.setText(secondPlayerName);
        }

    }

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        EditText firstPlayer = findViewById(R.id.firstPlayerName);
        EditText secondPlayer = findViewById(R.id.secondPlayerName);
        String firstPlayerName = String.valueOf(firstPlayer.getText());
        String secondPlayerName = String.valueOf(secondPlayer.getText());
        savedInstanceState.putString("firstPlayerName", firstPlayerName);
        savedInstanceState.putString("secondPlayerName", secondPlayerName);
    }

}
```

When I debugged it, I did notice it passed thru `onSavedInstance` and it did save the values, but once in onCreate, the `savedInstanceState` is null.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance & take care people.

Fares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You note that the "cancel button enables an Intent to go from B to A.". This sounds like you're creating a new instance of Activity A (so your activity stack goes A, B, A), and the instance state is specific to the individual instance.

Instead, you should return to A by simply calling `finish()` on B. This will return to the original instance of A, which will have your data.

Comment: Hey Ryan. Thanks for your answer. So In B I should call the ``finish()ˋ` method, am I correct? And that should send me back to A since I'd called B from A. I'll try that

Comment: To add to this answer as long as you dont call finish() in A when you start Activity B, when you call finish() in B, A should resume as expected @Fares

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan and @MichaelStoddart, I'll look up the activity stack too!